# PDF context into String from a blob

Tags: java, string, pdf, itext, blob

I want to extract PDF context into a String. I've done that previously using PDFBox but it doesn't support a lot of fonts I have in my PDFs.

Decided to use iText instead. How can I do that using getByteStream from a blob rather than a file on disk?

```
Blob blobPdf = ...;
File outputFile = new File("/tmp/blah/whatever.pdf");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
IOUtils.copy(blobPdf.getBinaryStream(), fout);
```

I want this sort of logic but insert the context into the String variable instead. How can I do that?

**@EDIT**

This is my attempt

```
InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream(3);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);

String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Can't you use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream()

Comment: I don't see any iText code in your code snippet. What is your exact problem? Do you have a blob and you don't know how to create a byte array? Or do you have a byte array and you don't know how to create a `PdfReader` instance? In your code, I see that you are trying to create a `File` object. Why would you need a file on disk if you can create a `PdfReader` from a byte array?

Comment: Also: you didn't mention which version of iText you intend to use. The most current version is iText 7.1.1. Text extraction in older versions such as 5.0.0 wasn't as advanced. Also note that text extraction from PDF is quite a challenge depending on the quality of your PDF. Are the PDF's from which you are trying to extract Tagged PDF's? If not, don't expect that the text extraction process will result in structured text.

Comment: Updated the thread with my attempt. Is it decent? It doesn't matter in what format the text comes in. I just want it in a string.

Comment: So you want to extract text from a PDF. Consider changing the word "context" to "text", it is confusing.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does the code bring an exception, does it bring nothing, does it bring the wrong text?